# Install Ubuntu 12.04 in ntfs or fat partition

Tags: system-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Ubuntu on a partition formatted as ntfs instead of ext4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123808/can-i-install-ubuntu-on-a-partition-formatted-as-ntfs-instead-of-ext4)

Install Ubuntu 12.04 in ntfs or fat partition, i wan't to install ubuntu 12.04 without converting to ext4 partition.. is that is possible?

Comment: No, you can't do that. Now, the question is why would you want to do that? Change your question to include the reason why you want to do this and we'll be able to answer more thoroughly, and perhaps help you find an alternative solution.

Comment: Agreed. This is not to be done. You can make your NTFS partition smaller and use an EXT4 partition next to it.

Comment: If possible, please consider closing some of your other open questions by [selecting the best answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer) (if they have one). Consider which answers have been useful and need an upvote. We need users to maintain their questions so that the site can be an effective tool for the next person with your problems. For more details on best practices consider reading [the FAQ on asking questions](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [windows installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows) to install it on the same partition as windows.
According to [This question](http://fixunix.com/ubuntu/344495-install-ubuntu-into-ntfs-partition.html) from another forum and [this question](http://www.ubuntux.org/is-it-okay-to-install-ubuntu-810-into-a-ntfs-partition) you can not use ntfs or fat as file system for a standard ubuntu install because it doesn't support the necessary priviliges.
I would always use a linux partition as the root and you can always make a data partition as ntfs that you can write to from both windows and linux. If you can't change the partitions you may be out of luck, though.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.

Comment: changed slightly to be more useful.

Comment: I would summarize the instructions in the pages you linked. If you do that, and then the links go down, users can still use your answer.

Comment: but ubuntu 11.04 we can install in ntfs parartion drivem,

Comment: @LiangLee That can make for an untable system. There is less risk installing to an ext4 partition by shrinking your NTFS partition.