# Ubuntu can't see my second Hard Disk

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive

I am a new Ubuntu (and Linux) user, this is my first attempt. I have a somewhat old Acer Intel Core2 Duo 2.20 GHzx2 with 3 GB RAM, I have two Hard Disks installed on it, its original 80 GB (SATA) Hard disk which is Drive C and recently I have installed a new Seagate 1 TB (SATA) which is Drive D
I installed Ubuntu 12.04 using Wubi from my Windows Vista, I opted to install it on Drive D and allocated the maximum 30 GB space for it, currently Drive D has around 750 GB free.

I have two Questions:

1. My windows run as 32bit and as far as I know my desktop computer cannot support 64bit, when I opened Ubuntu System Monitor it says Ubuntu Release 12.04 (precise) 64-bit, is this ok?
2. When I open the Home folder I can see my original hard Disk (Drive C) but my Seagate one (Drive D) doesn't show up, although in the system Monitor's System Status I have Available disk space: 719.5 GiB, and when I go to any folder on Computer (like Home, or Documents) and right-click and get properties it says Free Space 25.1 GiB although the free space on Drive C is 30 GiB (as confirmed by its properties from within Home Folder)

I as well have a 150GB external hard disk and it is recognised and show normally in Home Folder.

I am not really literate with Linux system, so this might be normal and that probably since Ubuntu is installed on drive D it doesn't need to show it, but I got puzzled with the 25.1 free space... or is there something I should do to make it detect drive D. I have read the other topics a bit similar to this but found that most have a different case and the closest case to mine was an issue with Ubuntu 13.04

Sorry for the long post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I install Ubuntu on a partition formatted as ntfs instead of ext4?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/123808/can-i-install-ubuntu-on-a-partition-formatted-as-ntfs-instead-of-ext4)

Answer (score 2):

I will answer my own questions since this turned out to be a very basic thing and this may help Linux noobs like myself. Since I am completely illiterate when it comes to Linux I thought that a Hard Disk can be shared between platforms such as Linux and Windows, using NTFS, which as I have seen can happen, but since I formatted my Sata drive using windows, Ubuntu was only able to see the space I had allocated for it in the installation. The solution would be to format it into ext3/4 and then the drive can be fully accessible by Ubuntu. If anyone wants to have a shared drive between both platforms here are some good discussions about this topic:

[What's the best way to share files between Linux and Windows 7...](https://superuser.com/questions/100629/whats-the-best-way-to-share-files-between-linux-and-windows-7-on-a-dual-multi-b) (SuperUser)

[File system compatible with all OSes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59585/file-system-compatible-with-all-oses/) (Unix & Linux)

In short Ubuntu is suppose to be ok with NTFS although I have no idea how stable it would be cross-platfoming, but the drive should be formatted from within Ubuntu. That was my conclusion after some researching, I hope I am not providing wrong information.